# How to change the order of items appearing in Spotlight with macOS Catalina/Big Sur?

Tags: mac, spotlight

[In an article on MacWorld from 2015](https://www.macworld.com/article/2902174/choosing-the-right-keyboard-based-launcher-utility.html), I saw the following image about changing the order in which items appear in Spotlight:

[image: Spotlight system preferences]

When I saw this, I wanted to change the order items appear on my Mac. 80% of my Spotlight use consists of looking up a definition in a dictionary. Currently I almost always have to scroll down to view the definition result, so I would like the dictionary to always show as the first category.

But on my Mac (macOS Catalina 10.15.6), the Spotlight window looks like this (it is Dutch) and I can't find anything about changing the order.

[image: Spotlight on my Mac]

Is there any other way to change the order of my Spotlight items? I currently still use Catalina, but perhaps on Big Sur? And does anyone know if this can be changed on iOS too?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: It certainly can\t be done on Mojave; looks like your image. Does the article you mention [but provide no link for] specify it's new to Big Sur?

Comment: Hi @Tetsujin thanks for responding. I added a link to the article in the question. My Mac has one of the latest versions of Catalina, 10.15.6.

Comment: Hmmm.. Article from 2015, which was Yosemite. I checked Macs here with Mojave, High Sierra & El Capitan - it doesn't appear on any of them.

Comment: Well, that's weird... Thanks for checking that!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found out after that Apple removed this feature from El Capitan. [See this question.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/216782/how-do-i-rearrange-the-order-of-spotlight-categories)

After a bit of additional searching, I found [that hitting `Cmd+L` brings you](https://www.reddit.com/r/OSXElCapitan/comments/3lf3tj/help_reorder_results_in_spotlight_searches/) straight to the dictionary definitions. There's an other solution which means recording items in a `plist` file, but as I'm no fan of directly 'modifying' the OS, I decided to stick with the `Cmd+L` solution.

Thanks to [Tetsujin](https://superuser.com/users/347380/tetsujin) for checking this on multiple older Macs!

Comment: +1 Nice find! :)

Comment: Yeah, thanks to you checking all those versions! That brought me to the conclusion that Apple had removed it. Have a nice weekend ;-)!

Comment: The `Cmd+L` trick sadly doesn't work anymore on Big Sur ([reference](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/jup4lu/big_sur_spotlight_and_dictionary_lookups/)).

Comment: Hi @goldfrapp04 yeah I also noticed it after updating to Big Sur. Tbh, I hate it.. And you also have to hit `enter` to show it! I now disabled every category except Apps, Definition and Calculator. Unfortunately it still shows a Safari search as the top item, so it's not so much of a use either..

Comment: Here's a good treatment on these changes in Big Sur: https://lacona.app/blog/2020/11/11/spotlight-changes-in-big-sur.

Comment: Thank you @seh, very attentive of you! In the article it was pointed out that you could use Cmd + Up/Down to go to the next section, I didn't know that, very handy!

Comment: I use spotlight only for opening applications and system preferences, so I deselected almost everything in the spotlight settings. Hopefully that will also make spotlight faster.

Comment: `⌘+L` works on macOS Monterey v12.2.1.

Comment: `Cmd+D` actually opens the definition directly (better than `Cmd+L`).
(As of macOS 13.6.1 Ventura.)

Answer (score 5):

Yeah as others have said, it has been taken away. Classic Apple being we know better :(

I sometimes use spotlight for dictionary too and usually the dictionary results are buried down below. One little trick I find useful is doing `cmd + down` arrow key to skip categories and go down faster.

Comment: Thanks that's very helpful, didn't know!